# How did wordpress 3.7 implement automatic updates ？

Tags: php, wordpress

> As we know wordpress can be Background Updates after 3.7 .

https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.7

I want to know that how it can be achieved ?

> I have find some thing for it.

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/update.php

> wp-admin/includes/class-wp-automatic-updater.php

---

But I found it upgraded even if I didn't visit the site (private site).

> no cron for wordpress.

Does it automatically upgrade through requests from search engines bot?

Or will worepress update server request all  wordpress website?

Answer (score 0):

The wordpress updates are automatic when they have critical updates so they sent auto update to the site. However you can manage the auto updates by changing constant values in `WP-CONFIG.PHP`

Add `define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );` to disable core updates (wordpress version update)

To disable plugin and theme updates , add the following in `functions.php` ,

Add `add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_false' );` to disable plugin updates.

Add `add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_false' );` to disable theme updates.

Here is an explanation of how the wordpress code update works : http://wpengineer.com/227/how-core-update-in-wordpress-27-works/

Wordpress triggers this file to update : `wp-admin/includes/update-core.php`

Comment: Sorry, I want to know  How did wordpress 3.7 implement automatic updates ？

Comment: Not how to disable the function .

Comment: Is it updated automatically when the user requests any site url?

Comment: Yes it will updated automatically when user request.. let me update my article

Comment: Your mean is worepress update server will request all the wordpress site ?

Comment: Yes they update the wordpress via their API request when we click 'Update wordpress' one click button